No video on vlc and other errors - raspberry PI 3A+ (Escape room project)
it's an amateur here trying to help a friend with an escape room project. Briefly explained: the raspberry will receive a GPIO signal from an item in the room, then a 60 seconds video will immediatly play and after 40 seconds from the start of the video, the raspberry will send a signal to open a door.
This is the code:
import time
import vlc
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
while True:
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
if GPIO.input(4):

    instance = vlc.Instance ('--aout=alsa')
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    video = instance.media_new('file:///home/marvel/Desktop/video.mp4')
    player.set_media(video)
    player.play()
    player.set_fullscreen(True)
    time.sleep(40)

    GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(14, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(14, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()

time.sleep(60)

These are the errors I get when starting the code manually
still other errors with manual start
The main problem is that when it starts automatically on startup (I've used rc.local for that), the code runs, but it only plays sound and no video Also, both automatic and manual, have a 50/60 seconds delay to start
Any help on how to solve these problems is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

please, no pictures of text, or worse, links to pictures of text ... post thevtext instead... format as code for readability

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
